# Button next to my entry always shows below the entry

Tags: html, css

I have a blog I am building with entries. I have a form with hidden variables to submit the entryID and other data to "delete" the post.  The button always shows below the entry, instead of beside it.

I have tried using CSS Clear, and putting everything in a single `<p>` line to see if that helps. I feel like the issue is that there is a form with hidden variables, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
 <div id="subformposts">
    <?php echo $subentry['Body']; ?>
    <?php echo $subentry['CreateDate']; ?> - <?php echo $subentry['UserName']; ?><br />

<!-- Determine whether to show the delete button -->
<form action="Delete_entry.php" method="post" id="Deletesub<?php echo $subentry['EntryID'];?>" onsubmit="return confirmdelete('Deletesub<?php echo $subentry['EntryID'];?>')">     
        <input type="hidden" readonly="true" name="EntryID" value="<?php echo $subentry['EntryID']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" readonly="true" name="UserID" value="<?php echo $subentry['UserID']; ?>" />
        <?php if ($userid == 1 || $userid == $res['UserID']) { ?>
        <input type="image" src="redx.png" alt="Delete Post" id="btnDelete" value="Delete Post" />
    <?php } ?>
</form>
</div>
```

I want to see the button floating to the right of my entry, (or to the left at this point.) If I could have it tucked into the div that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-flex` on `subformposts`.

Like this one :

```
<div id="subformposts" style="display: inline-flex;">
<?php echo $subentry['Body']; ?>
<?php echo $subentry['CreateDate']; ?> - <?php echo $subentry['UserName']; ?><br />

<!-- Determine whether to show the delete button -->
<form action="Delete_entry.php" method="post" id="Deletesub<?php echo 
$subentry['EntryID'];?>" onsubmit="return confirmdelete('Deletesub<?php echo $subentry['EntryID'];?>')">     
    <input type="hidden" readonly="true" name="EntryID" value="<?php echo $subentry['EntryID']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" readonly="true" name="UserID" value="<?php echo $subentry['UserID']; ?>" />
    <?php if ($userid == 1 || $userid == $res['UserID']) { ?>
    <input type="image" src="redx.png" alt="Delete Post" id="btnDelete" value="Delete Post" />
<?php } ?>
</form>
</div>
```

Or you can keep both in two different `div` and put `display:inline-block` on both of those div. Like this .

```
 <div id="subformposts" style="display: inline-block;">
 <?php echo $subentry['Body']; ?>
 <?php echo $subentry['CreateDate']; ?> - <?php echo $subentry['UserName']; ?><br />
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
<!-- Determine whether to show the delete button -->
 <form action="Delete_entry.php" method="post" id="Deletesub<?php echo 
 $subentry['EntryID'];?>" onsubmit="return confirmdelete('Deletesub<?php echo $subentry['EntryID'];?>')">     
<input type="hidden" readonly="true" name="EntryID" value="<?php echo 
$subentry['EntryID']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" readonly="true" name="UserID" value="<?php echo 
$subentry['UserID']; ?>" />
<?php if ($userid == 1 || $userid == $res['UserID']) { ?>
<input type="image" src="redx.png" alt="Delete Post" id="btnDelete" value="Delete Post" />
<?php } ?>
</form>
</div>
```